# How to make a Button not resizable in a JSP page

Tags: html, css, jsp, button, web-applications

Easy question: I've a button like this in my JSP page

```
<input type="button" class="MyButton" disabled>
```

and this is the CSS style:

```
.MyButton{

background-color:#44c767;
border:1px solid #18ab29;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:15px 21px;
text-decoration:none;

}
.MyButton:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.MyButton:active {
 position:relative; 
}
```

I wish my button doesn't change size when the value is set, for example:

```
<input type="button" class="MyButton" value="1" disabled>
```

If my button has sizes width: 10px and heigth: 10px, I want that continue to have that sizes also with the value parameter

How could I do that?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your css file, Try:

```
.MyButton {width: 150px}
```

or

```
.MyButton {width: 150px !important;}
```

Comment: I followed your advice, but now the text inside the button is not centered. I tried to put "text-align: center;" but doesn't work, any suggest?

Comment: I just add width: 44px; heigth: 44px; (these are the sizes of my button)

Comment: @Zoythrus, Did you add the text align I mentioned above?

Comment: @Zoythrus, Place line-height: 150px; at the end of your .MyButton block